# A question on the proof of the inequality $ \sum_{k} |I_{k}| \leq |I| $, where $ I $ and the $ I_{k} $’s are intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

> **Theorem.** If $ \displaystyle \bigcup_{k} I_{k} \subseteq I $ and the $ I_{k} $’s are disjoint, then $ \displaystyle \sum_{k} |I_{k}| \leq |I| $.

I can understand the proof for the finite case, but when it passes to the infinite case, I am quite lost. The text claims that “if there are infinitely many intervals, then there exist finite subcollections that satisfy finite additivity”.

My question is: How do we know that there exist finite subcollections from a collection of infinitely many intervals?

Comment: For the infinite (but *countable*!) case, just note that it holds in *every* finite case, then take the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any set $X$ and integer $n$ you can form the subset of the power set of  X
$$X_n:= \{A\subset X: \#A = n\}$$
which will be not empty (where # denotes the cardinality). If now $X$ is your collection of intervals then this way you get the finite subcollections.